# Wordpress twitter plugin

Tags: twitter, wordpress

I was using a wordpress plugin "**Twitter for Wordpress**" [located in wordpress plugins directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-for-wordpress/) then it seems to suddenly stopped fetching my tweets showing "No public Twitter messages".

I went to the plugin url and find that the demo showing the same error message and I tried to contact the developer for code update as this plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress with no success.

As being not familiar with PHP I am asking anyone who may assist me with code modifying so that the plugin could back to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, can you look at plugin configurations or inside PHP code for Twitter resource URLs? Since Twitter has dropped version "0", legacy code is probably the issue.

See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

Else, you should look at another plugin solution. Twitter is always improving, you need a plugin that follows updates